# jQuery Mobile/Phonegap build - First page transition missing

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, transition

I built a test-page in html/jQM. It's just one html-file.
I built an .apk with phonegap-build to test it on my galaxy s4 (4.2.2).

My problem is, that the first page transition is not showing. It doens't matter which transition I choose (slide, pop, fade, flip, ...). Alsways the first transition isn't there.

I tried href="#blabla" and changePage("#blabla").

If I change the page (transition not showing), go back and change page again, the transition is there. It's just always missing on the first time.

All other page transitions work.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="index_list">
            <!-- Liste wird mit jQuery gefüllt! -->
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="page2_list">
            <!-- Liste wird mit jQuery gefüllt! -->
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="page3_list">
            <!-- Liste wird mit jQuery gefüllt! -->
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="page4_list">
            <!-- Liste wird mit jQuery gefüllt! -->
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="index2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="index2_list">
            <li>Hallo</li>
            <li>Velo</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="index3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role = "listview" id="index3_list">
            <li>Hallo3</li>
            <li>Velo3</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        //var output = $('#output');

        $.ajax({
            //url: 'http://localhost/jsontest/lcl_request_grp.php',
            url: 'XXX',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: 'data',
            jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data, status){

                var html = '';
                var list = [];
                $.each(data, function(i,item){

                    //Alle Werte in einen Array Schreiben
                    //i beginnt bei 0
                    list[i] = [];
                    list[i]={};
                    list[i]['grp_id'] = item.grp_id;
                    list[i]['bezeichnung_de'] = item.bezeichnung_de;
                    list[i]['parent'] = item.parent;
                    list[i]['end'] = item.end;
                    list[i]['bezeichnung_fr'] = item.bezeichnung_fr;
                    list[i]['bezeichnung_en'] = item.bezeichnung_en;

                    //Die Werte die als parent 0 haben, in die Liste schreiben
                    if (item.parent == 0) {
                        html += '<li id="' + item.grp_id + '" parent = "' + item.parent +'"><a href="#" id="' + item.grp_id + '">' + item.bezeichnung_de + '</a></li>';
                    }
                });

                $('#index_list').append($(html));
                $('#index_list').trigger('create');    
                $('#index_list').listview('refresh');

                // Daten im LocalStorage als JSON-String speichern
                localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));

            },
            error: function(){
                window.alert("error!")
            }
        });

        $('#index_list').on('click', 'li', function() {
            var eintragid = $(this).attr('id');
            p_changepage(eintragid, "#page2", "#page2_list");
        });

        $( "#index" ).on( "swiperight", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index3", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true,
            });   
        });

        $( "#index" ).on( "swipeleft", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
            });   
        });

        $( "#index2" ).on( "swiperight", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true,
            });   
        });

        $( "#index2" ).on( "swipeleft", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index3", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
            });   
        });

        $( "#index3" ).on( "swipeleft", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: false,
            });   
        });

        $( "#index3" ).on( "swiperight", function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", {
                transition: "slide",
                reverse: true,
            });   
        });

        $('#page2_list').on('click', 'li', function() {
            var eintragid = $(this).attr('id');
            p_changepage(eintragid, "#page3", "#page3_list");
        });

        $('#page3_list').on('click', 'li', function() {
            var eintragid = $(this).attr('id');
            p_changepage(eintragid, "#page4", "#page4_list");
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the external 'java.js':

```
function p_changepage (eintragid, topage, tolist) {
    alert(window.location.pathname);
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
    var html = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        if (item.parent == eintragid) {
            html += '<li id="' + item.grp_id + '" parent = "' + item.parent +'"><a href="#" id="' + item.grp_id + '">' + item.bezeichnung_de + '</a></li>';
        }
    });

    $(tolist).empty(); 
    $(tolist).append($(html));
    $(tolist).trigger('create'); 
    $.mobile.changePage( topage, {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: false,
    });   
    $(tolist).listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: can you post html5 code?

Comment: is posted now in the original question.

Comment: Can you say from which page to which page you need to transist n when??

Comment: You can see it in the html code. It's just the first transition from index to another page. Doesn't matter if i swipe to 'index2' or click on the list to 'page2'.

Comment: I dont quite see the problem. I tried your code, i can "slide" on all pages.  I dont experience any issues on the sliding.  Did you find a solution and posted it already in the code?

Comment: I just tried to change all to "pop".  Works fine.  :O

Comment: Did you test it in browser or with an build.phonegap-apk? On Broweser it does also work for me. But as soon as I build an apk with build.phonegap it doesn't work anymore :(